# How to get mean for non consecutive group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to filter the data, to have only one value on (y) group by (x)
The aggregation could be the Mean(y)
The problem : a group on (x) must be consecutive over (Date)

Here is an example of the data

```
| DATE                    |   x   |  y |
---------------------------------------
| 2017-03-12 13:52:38.707 | 77.01 |  3 |
| 2017-03-12 13:52:55.607 | 77.01 |  5 |
| 2017-03-12 13:53:54.920 | 78.89 |  7 |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:12.320 | 78.89 |  8 |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:50.287 | 78.89 |  6 |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:07.130 | 89.31 |  5 |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:44.997 | 89.31 |  4 |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.200 | 16.13 |  9 |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.400 | 16.13 | 10 |
| 2017-03-12 14:00:33.240 | 16.13 | 13 |
| 2017-03-12 14:03:04.450 | 19.01 |  8 |
| 2017-03-12 14:04:59.250 | 77.01 | 12 |
| 2017-03-12 14:05:37.707 | 77.01 | 15 |
| 2017-03-12 14:07:30.517 | 77.01 | 14 |
| 2017-03-12 14:08:29.757 | 78.89 |  8 |
```

What I have till now: See the problem with the value 77.01 on (x)

```
| DATE                    |   x   |  y | Grp |
----------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-12 13:52:38.707 | 77.01 |  3 |  1  |
| 2017-03-12 13:52:55.607 | 77.01 |  5 |  1  |
| 2017-03-12 13:53:54.920 | 78.89 |  7 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:12.320 | 78.89 |  8 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:50.287 | 78.89 |  6 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:07.130 | 89.31 |  5 |  3  |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:44.997 | 89.31 |  4 |  3  |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.200 | 16.13 |  9 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.400 | 16.13 | 10 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 14:00:33.240 | 16.13 | 13 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 14:03:04.450 | 19.01 |  8 |  5  |
| 2017-03-12 14:04:59.250 | 77.01 | 12 |  1  |-
| 2017-03-12 14:05:37.707 | 77.01 | 15 |  1  |-- must be group 6 not 1
| 2017-03-12 14:07:30.517 | 77.01 | 14 |  1  |-
| 2017-03-12 14:08:29.757 | 78.89 |  8 |  6  |
```

What I want:

```
| DATE                    |   x   |  y | Grp |
----------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-12 13:52:38.707 | 77.01 |  3 |  1  |
| 2017-03-12 13:52:55.607 | 77.01 |  5 |  1  |
| 2017-03-12 13:53:54.920 | 78.89 |  7 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:12.320 | 78.89 |  8 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:54:50.287 | 78.89 |  6 |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:07.130 | 89.31 |  5 |  3  |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:44.997 | 89.31 |  4 |  3  |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.200 | 16.13 |  9 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.400 | 16.13 | 10 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 14:00:33.240 | 16.13 | 13 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 14:03:04.450 | 19.01 |  8 |  5  |
| 2017-03-12 14:04:59.250 | 77.01 | 12 |  6  |
| 2017-03-12 14:05:37.707 | 77.01 | 15 |  6  |
| 2017-03-12 14:07:30.517 | 77.01 | 14 |  6  |
| 2017-03-12 14:08:29.757 | 78.89 |  8 |  7  |
```

So that it could be possible to have the Mean(y) by Grp

```
| DATE                    |   x   |Mean(y)| Grp |
----------------------------------------------
| 2017-03-12 13:52:38.707 | 77.01 |  4    |  1  |
| 2017-03-12 13:53:54.920 | 78.89 |  7    |  2  |
| 2017-03-12 13:56:07.130 | 89.31 |  4.5  |  3  |
| 2017-03-12 13:59:55.200 | 16.13 | 10.66 |  4  |
| 2017-03-12 14:03:04.450 | 19.01 |  8    |  5  |
| 2017-03-12 14:04:59.250 | 77.01 | 13.66 |  6  |
| 2017-03-12 14:08:29.757 | 78.89 |  8    |  7  |
```

I have tried with GROUPBY or with OVER but each time I have the problem with the value 77,01. I retreive only one Group

```
SELECT [TS.DATE], TS.X, t_index = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TS.X)
FROM TS
```

Does anyone can help me ?
Thank you.

PS:Apologies about my English

Comment: sorry not able to get what's the problem. Can you please explain what is the issue with expected result and the actual result?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the grouping?

Comment: For x value ordered by Date. I wand to increment a groupid over each transition on x.
So each time the x value change, I want to increment the groupid. Then with the groupid column I can I the mean(y) for each group.
I am cleared or is it always confused ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the groups using a difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by x, (seqnum - seqnum_x)) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by x order by date) as seqnum_x
      from t
     ) t;
```

The logic here is a bit tricky.  To understand it, run the subquery.  Stare at the results and you will see why the difference identifies each group.

To get the average:

```
select t.x, avg(y),
       min(date), max(date),
       dense_rank() over (order min(date)) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by x order by date) as seqnum_x
      from t
     ) t
group by x, (seqnum - seqnum_x)
```

This generates the group numbers in order (because the assignment is after the aggregation).

The above identifies each group, but the original query does not generate the group numbers in order by date.  An alternative which does this is to use `lag()` and cumulative `sum()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_x = x then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(x) over (order by date) as prev_x
      from t
     ) t;
```

The logic here is simpler.  Just look at the previous value and add up a flag when it changes.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. The first method is a little more tricky than the 2nd. But I like both.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below uses a lot of window functions, but gets the results.

The date value is based on the median value.

It uses the same trick that Gordon Linoff used by subtracting 2 rownumbers to get a usefull ranking.

```
select max([DATE]), X, avg_y as [Mean(y)], row_number() over (order by max([DATE])) as Grp
from (
    select *,
    PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Y) OVER (PARTITION BY X, RN_DIFF) as median_y,
    CAST(AVG(Y * 1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY X, RN_DIFF) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) as avg_y
    from(
        select [DATE], X, Y, 
        row_number() over (order by [DATE]) - row_number() over (partition by x order by [DATE]) as RN_DIFF
        from TS t
        ) q1
) q2
where median_y = y
group by X, avg_y, RN_DIFF
order by max([DATE]);
```